# Display formatted raw html with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a place where I am trying to show code in a text area.  I have dumbed down the example but basically user can input some fields, click a button, and the code snippet displays in a text area below for them to edit if they want and then copy.

I finally got it working to display the actual code snippet.  But now I can't seem to find a way to format it so that it is indented and looks nice.

```
var mySnippet =
"<div id=\"myOuterDiv\">"
    + "<div id=\"myInnerDiv\">"
    + "</div>"
    + "</div>";
$('#mySnippetArea').text(mySnippet);
```

Which displays in my text area like so.

```
<div id="myOuterDiv"><div id="myInnerDiv"></div></div>
```

Where as I would like to see it as:

```
    <div id="myOuterDiv">
        <div id="myInnerDiv">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'd really like to avoid any 3rd party plugins as its for work an a pain to get approval.  It's just 4 small snippets I need to format.

**UPDATE**
This appears to work as I need.

```
var mySnippet =
        "<div id=\"myOuterDiv\">\r"
            + "    <div id=\"myInnerDiv\">\r"
            + "    </div>\r"
            + "</div>\r";
```

Output:

```
<div id="myOuterDiv">
    <div id="myInnerDiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use \t: horizontal tab instead of multiple backspace for indention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `\n` if you want a new line like

```
var mySnippet = "<div id=\"myOuterDiv\">\n"
    + "<div id=\"myInnerDiv\">\n"
    + "</div>\n"
    + "</div>\n";
$('#mySnippetArea').text(eventSnippet);
```

**Single character escape sequences:**

```
\b: backspace (U+0008 BACKSPACE)
\f: form feed (U+000C FORM FEED)
\n: line feed (U+000A LINE FEED)
\r: carriage return (U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN)
\t: horizontal tab (U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION)
\v: vertical tab (U+000B LINE TABULATION)
\0: null character (U+0000 NULL)
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jtx7e/

Comment: You'll have to pad your own spaces for indentation as well.

Comment: Adding a \n where noted is not causing a line break? It is just causing there to be a blank space in between the divs now (ex <div> <div> instead of <div><div>)

Comment: @Adam are you using the <pre> tag?

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano no I am not using the <pre> tag.  I found that this answer works if you use \r not \n.

Comment: I am not exactly sure why \n doesn't work for me in my application.

Comment: @Adam if you doesn't use the <pre> tag you need to set css `{ white-space:pre; }` for the mySnippetArea element to use \n and the spaces and other escape sequences

Comment: In your code you have eventSnippet and mySnippet, are you sure this is right? Should it not be $('#mySnippetArea').text(mySnippet); ?

Comment: @artworkad yes I have it correct in my app, just a typo here thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

just use `<pre id="mySnippetArea"></pre>` and add \n and space according to the needed layout

edit:

you can also write

```
var mySnippet =
"<div id=\"myOuterDiv\">\n\
   <div id=\"myInnerDiv\">\n\
   </div>\n\
</div>";
```

Comment: @ShawnChin indeed i specified you need to add \n and spaces to the text to be rendered